# How to disable recycler view auto scrolling?

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently working on a kotlin mobile application. The problem I have met is if there are having 3 reviews or above, the recycler view will auto generate a scroll bar on the right side and the display will become not so good. May I know that is there anyway to disable scroll bar of the recycler view so that my layout can view all the reviews by just add a scrollview on the layout?

[image]

Comment: Recyclerview usually doesnt come with a scrollbar, can you post a screenshot of your actual app screen?

Comment: @RobertoFortunato I solved it accidentally by using nestedscrollview on the layout. Thanks anyway sir !